# Panning leaflet map or Plotly plot in draggable Shiny panel also moves panel

Tags: shiny, r-plotly, r-leaflet

When using a leaflet map inside a draggable Shiny panel (e.g. absolutePanel with draggable=T), panning the leaflet map with the mouse also drags the Shiny panel.

Is there a way to prevent panning the map with the mouse from also moving the Shiny panel?

I think it is similar to this resolved issue:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/711

and there are DOM event functions related to click propagation in leaflet.

## Edit:

This also occurs with Plotly plots and may be a more general issue than I initially realized. The question has been edited to include plotly.

## Leaflet example:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    absolutePanel(draggable=T, width='600px', wellPanel(
        fluidRow(leafletOutput('map'))
    ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$map=renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)
    }) 
  }
)
```

Setting the dragging option to F in leaflet resolves the problem, but makes the map less useful.

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    absolutePanel(draggable=T, width='600px', wellPanel(
        fluidRow(leafletOutput('map'))
    ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$map=renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(options=leafletOptions(dragging=F)) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)
    }) 
  }
)
```

## Plotly example

Zoom, pan, and select plot interactions all cause the draggable panel to move.

```r
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    absolutePanel(draggable=T, width='600px', wellPanel(
        fluidRow(plotlyOutput('plot'))
    ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot=renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(data=mtcars, type='scatter', mode='markers', x=~hp, y=~mpg, name=~cyl)
    })
  }
)
```